# How to Avoid negative values error when using TruncatedSVD?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've got a document classification problem with only 2 classes and my training dataset matrix size after the CountVectorizer/TfidfVectorizer becomes (40,845 X 218,904) (unigram). I'd like to use TruncatedSVD; however, CountVectorizer/TfidfVectorizer seems to produce negative values. I'd like to know why and how negative values can be avoided.

```
    tsvd = TruncatedSVD(10000, algorithm="randomized")

      features = [
                dict(name="count_ng1",
                feat=CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenizer, ngram_range=(1,1))),
                dict(name="tfidf_ng1",
                feat=TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenizer, ngram_range=(1,1))),
               ]
           for data in datas:
               (D_train, y_train, d_test, y_test) = g.get_train_test(**data['params'])

              for feat in features:
                  x_train = feat['feat'].fit_transform(d_train)
                  x_test = feat['feat'].transform(d_test)
                  X_trainSVD = tsvd.fit_transform(x_train)
                  X_testSVD = tsvd.transform(x_test)
```

Comment: you should include some code

Comment: I've added some code. It is just the use of the necessary functions from the sklearn package

Comment: it does not look like a valid python indentation, in order to ask a good question (and so - receive valuable answers) you have to prepare a short, reproducable example

Comment: See: 
http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Also please always mention the versions of libraries you are using (in this case scikit-learn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TruncatedSVD` should have no problem processing negative values.

`CountVectorizer`/`TfidfVectorizer` should not produce negative values. If they do, it's probably a bug.

I will update my answer if you update your question to:

- provide us with a valid reproduction script, preferably on self-contained data if possible (e.g. define `d_train` / `d_test` as small list of Python strings that make it possible to reproduce the issue without having access to your real data),
- fix the indentation to make it possible to copy and paste your code snippet and run it,
- provide the error message you get along with the full traceback.